# ComboBox SelectedItem Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, observablecollection

I have a ComboBox in my **View**:

```
<ComboBox Name="comboBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding MandantList}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentMandant, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Firma}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Here is my **Model**:

```
public class MandantListItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MandantListItem() { }

    string _Firma;
    bool _IsChecked;

    public string Firma
    {
        get { return _Firma; }
        set { _Firma = value; }
    }
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get
        {
            return _IsChecked;
        }
        set
        {
            _IsChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsChecked));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And here is my **ViewModel**:

```
public class MaViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<MandantListItem> MandantList { get { return _MandantList; } }
    public ObservableCollection<MandantListItem> _MandantList = new ObservableCollection<MandantListItem>();

    private MandantListItem _CurrentMandant;
    public MandantListItem CurrentMandant
    {
        get { return _CurrentMandant; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _CurrentMandant)
            {
                _CurrentMandant = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentMandant");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

How to fill the ComboBox:

```
public zTiredV2.ViewModel.MaViewModel MAList = new zTiredV2.ViewModel.MaViewModel();
this.comboBox1.ItemsSource = MAList.MandantList;
MAList.MandantList.Add(new zTiredV2.Model.MandantListItem { Firma = "A", Homepage = "a.com", IsChecked = false });
MAList.MandantList.Add(new zTiredV2.Model.MandantListItem { Firma = "B", Homepage = "b.com", IsChecked = false });
```

But my item doesnt update ... tried also via IsChecked, but no success either ... when i iterate through MAList, IsChecked is always false. And how can i bind a TextBlock to the selected Firma?

Have a hard time with MVVM, but i like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the `DataContext` of the `ComboBox` to an instance of your view model. Otherwise the bindings won't work:

```
this.comboBox1.DataContext = MAList;
```

Also note that the `_MandantList` backing field for your property shouldn't be public. In fact, you don't need it at all:

```
public ObservableCollection<MandantListItem> MandantList { get; } = new ObservableCollection<MandantListItem>();
```

Setting the `DataContext` should cause the `CurrentMandant` property to get set when you select an item in the `ComboBox`. It won't set the `IsChecked` property though.

Comment: U are a genius!!! Searched for several hours ... and a simple `this.comboBox1.DataContext = MAList;` solved my problem. Thanks also for the help for the backing field!

Comment: @DerKiLLa: Note that you generally set the `DataContext` of the entire window and let the controls, such as the `ComboBox` in this case, inherit it.

Comment: Okay ... Also got my binding of a TextBlock with `<TextBlock x:Name="website"  Text="{Binding CurrentMandant.Homepage}"/>` Really simple in the end :D